# Git - Get the difference between branches of two repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-diff, git-difftool

How can we get the list of files differences between two branches residing in two separate repositories

Scenario: Suppose we have 2 repositories 'A' & 'B', B was created from A since A is the base repo. Now the development work has been taking place since long on both this repositories 'A' with branch 'support/v1' and 'B' with branch 'master'. I want to find and check which files are missing with 'B'. In short need an list of files difference between branches of this two repo.

```
repo  branches
A   => support/v1
B   => master
```

Need help to find the list of files using git

Comment: Add both repos as remotes, fetch from them, then do `git diff B/master A/support/v1`.

Comment: Were these two repos forked from each other?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No they weren't, completely different repos

Comment: @MeenaPanchal your question states "B was created from A, since A is the base repo". But your comment says "completely different repos". Which one is it? Do they share common history or not?

Comment: @knittl No they don't actually share any common history. B was created with reference to A. I mean using the file and structure from A. They are separate entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both repos as a remote in your local repository and then run diff like you would for any other branches:

```
git clone pathorurl/to/A.git
cd A
git remote add B pathorurl/to/B.git
git fetch --all
git diff origin/support/v1 B/master
```

This will work for any two repositories, because `git diff` only looks at *tree* objects and is not interested in commit history.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have a 3rd repo that can see them *both* as remotes... *or* take one of them and add the other as a remote. Once you fetch the remote (or remotes, if having a 3rd repo with the 2 remotes), you should be able to see differences between whatever branches.

So... using the third repo approach:

```
git clone A some-directory
cd some-directory
# this repo has repo A as _origin_
git remote add repoB url-to-b
git fetch repoB
# now you can take branches and compare them (among many other things you can do)
git diff origin/support/v1 repoB/master
```

Answer (score 0):

If git history was retained, you can try git diff as other answers suggest. If there was no git history, and was a separate commit, then you may try tools like Win Merge to compare the folders/files line by line. Also, some IDE's like IntelliJ Idea support this.

Comment: `git diff` does not care about common histories. It can compare two commits even if there is no common history behind them.